# Which site to ask a technology's theory?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which site to ask a software technology's theory?

Such as [ngrok](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok),

there have the source code, but I don't know the deep theory. there is also no detail description of it.

is there any site I can ask this type question?

the StackOverflow only accept the code questions, not appropriate.

---

**EDIT-01**

My first example(`ngrok`) is not good.
if there is a practical technology, such as VPN, such as PPTP, GRE and so on, I want to know its theory, still no site in SE suitable?
if you say [networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but it only accept questions under layer 3. the VPN technology is belong to application layer.

Comment: The only one that can answer this is the author of the code, so I don't think there is any suitable Stack Exchange site for this type of question.

Comment: I don't think this would be suitable on any SE site. By simply clicking on the project homepage I was taken to a large page containing documentation for this, your claim that there is no detail is very wrong, the docs are extensive https://ngrok.com/docs

Comment: @Mark shouldn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @mindstormsboi I am not too sure really as most of the comment is just commentary. I couldn't decide, so I just left a comment. If you think you can expand that comment in to a valid answer, feel free to do so. I'm a bit undecided on it.

Comment: To address your edit, "How does technology X work?" would be too broad for any site on SE, it is simply too complex to answer in the SE format. What you seem to be looking for is a full education on a subject. The best options I can see for you would be either sign up for an online course in the subject (many are free) or visit a specific forum that specializes in a subject.

Answer (score 2):

To quote you:  "*there is also no detail description of it*" - that is incorrect.  I have looked at the Ngrok docs [here](https://ngrok.com/docs), and it seems to be pretty in-depth.

Asking how a technology works, or about it's theory, would not be suitable on Stack Exchange.  To learn more about that, I would recommend signing up for a course in that topic instead of asking elsewhere on SE.